# How to add total distance to HKLiveWorkouts

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am using the new HKLiveWorkoutBuilder to create a Healthkit Workout. All is well except that I can't figure out how to give the workout a total distance. I add the distance sample which works (although it shows the unit twice in Health e.g. 200 mi mi) but when querying the workout later it does not have a total distance, and even in the workout builders finishWorkout() function the workout does not have a total distance. Does anyone know how I can get total distance on Live Workouts?

Comment: Show the code you think is causing the issue. Remember showing the code related to the issue will help get the correct answers.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like setting the activity type on the HKWorkoutConfiguration() is the answer. I was using "other" as the activity type and for whatever reason the resulting HKWorkout does not have a total distance. I switched the activity type to walking and it works fine.

Comment: currently having the same problem – but using HKWorkoutBuilder instead. But setting the `activityType` doesnt helped. Any other suggestions? Even the double units in health app.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like HKLiveWorkoutBuilder creates an HKWorkout for you, but instead only provides you with incremental data as the workout session progresses.

Since HKWorkout is immutable, you should create one only once all its data is collected. Then once you want to save the workout, you could re-query all relevant data from the Health store, or use the samples collected realtime.

Use the `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier` for the "distance traveled" e.g. :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier/1615230-distancewalkingrunning
to query for the value before initializing the HKWorkout.